# How can I slice a row from a certain column onwards using loc in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

The following piece of code is getting the data from Excel in the 5th row and the 14th row:

```
import pandas as pd
import pymssql
df=[]
fp = "G:\\Data\\Hotels\\ABZPD - Daily Strategy Tool.xlsm" 
data = pd.read_excel(fp,sheet_name ="CRM View" )
row_date = data.loc[3, :]
row_sita = "ABZPD"
row_event = data.iloc[11, :]

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': row_date,
                           'sita': row_sita,
                           'event': row_event
                           })
print(df)
```

Now, I do still want the 5th row and 14th row but I only want it to read from column D onwards in the Excel sheet. How do I do this?

Comment: `data.loc[3, 'D':]` and `data.iloc[11, 'D':]`

Comment: @COLDSPEED this gives "Key Error: 'D' "

Comment: Do your column names not contain 'D'?

Comment: @COLDSPEED what do you mean? An excel worksheet has numerical rows and 'A-Z' labelled columns...

Answer (score 1):

`loc` works with strings when specifying column slices:

```
c = df.columns[3] # column name in column "D"
data.loc[3, c:]
```